# A few Stored Procedures on sql server values are interchanged

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

My service is deployed on a few IIS and they execute a considerable number of instances (100-200) of 3-4 different Stored procedures simultaneously. The SPs are executed Via "executescalar".

All SPs are returning different value types. I realized that the values have been replaced for SP calls that are made at same time. I am sure about this because I got invalid cast exception for all calls, and SP logging was correct.

Could somebody tell me what's gone wrong!!!

-Thanks

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [DBO].[SPO_DATABASESERVER_GET_CONTEXT_FROMNWACCOUNTID_1.0.5]
            @NwAccountId      BIGINT  = NULL,              
            @ActionFlag VARCHAR(20) = 'NONE'      
AS

BEGIN    
DECLARE @DBID BIGINT
DECLARE @ConnectionString VARCHAR(250)    

IF COALESCE(@NWACCOUNTID,'') != ''                                      
    BEGIN           
      SELECT @DBID = DATABASEID
      FROM   NWACCOUNTMASTER
      WHERE  NWACCOUNTMASTERID = @NWACCOUNTID                                     
    END

 IF (COALESCE(@DBID,'') = '')
    BEGIN 
        RAISERROR ('No DB is assigned for NwAccountId %I64d.',16,1,@NwAccountId)
        RETURN 
    END

  IF EXISTS (SELECT 'X'
         FROM   ACDATABASESERVER
         WHERE  DATABASEID = @DBID)
  BEGIN
      SELECT
           @ConnectionString = CONNECTIONSTRING
      FROM   ACDATABASESERVER
      WHERE  DATABASEID = @DBID
  END

  IF (COALESCE(@ConnectionString,'') = '')
  BEGIN 
        RAISERROR ('SP failed to fetch ConnectionString for NwAccountId %I64d.',16,1,@NwAccountId)
        RETURN 
  END

SELECT @ConnectionString AS CONNECTIONSTRING
END
```

Comment: I think we'll need to see the code in the SPs tha are not behaving themselves

Comment: code is there for one troubled SP. The second execution is a Query - string.Format("select networkId from acgroup where groupId ={0}", p_nGroupId); followed by object nNetworkId = oSqlFramework.GetScalarData(sql);    ... There values have been interchanged. The query returns an int while the above SP returns a string. but they are interchanged and causing invalid cast exceptions.

Comment: You still have not explained what is going wrong... how many stored procedures? How many ways of calling SQL? select networkId from acgroup where groupId ={0} is not a stored proc.

Comment: There are a few stored procedures (3-4 but in different app stacks) that might be running at the same time. Some are returning multiple values.  sql calls are done in many ways -

Comment: 1. direct string query execution 2. SP execution as non query, 3. SP execution as scalar. as mentioned in my question, the problem is - the return values of 1. string query select networkId... and 2. stored procedure (mentioned above, that are executed as scalar)  are interchanged. these two execution are done on same server but different databases. 1 has returned type int and 2 has string as returned type.  ---- This issue is not consistent. Apears with gap of 2-3 days .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"invalid cast exception" is not a SQL error...

Do you have different web code that expects different return types for the same stored proc?

It's *impossible* for SQL to have mixed or changing different return datatypes if every IIS calls the same server/database/stored proc and the stored proc has the same outout signature. The only causes could be:

- different databases
- different SQL Servers
- stored procedures have `IF SELECT int, varchar... ELSE SELECT varchar, int...`
- dynamic SQL

Comment: Thanks, Invalid cast is not coming through SP, I got this exception in the code while implicitly casting the returned value from Executescalar method. There are no conditional branches. There is only select @param statement at the end. Which is of different type for diff SP.  but in one of the executions I use following query - string.Format("select networkId from acgroup where groupId ={0}", p_nGroupId); followed by object nNetworkId = oSqlFramework.GetScalarData(sql);

Comment: There is your error then: don't use the same client code to issue the same SQL

Comment: could you elaborate a bit more. Which client code? to issue same SQL?

Comment: you mean oSqlFramework? this instance is created fresh for each sql call.